# Retornar data que faltam x dias para chegar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, expressões-lambda

Cenario:

```
Ciclos
id 
name
endDate (datetime?)
```

Dados:

```
1, primeiro, 05/10/2017
2, segundo, 15/10/2017
3, terceiro, 20/10/2017
4, quarto, 30/10/2017
```

Com linq e lambda, gostaria de retornar as datas que sejam acima da data atual, porem estejam abaixo de uma determinada quantidade de dias informada pelo usuário.

Exemplo se hoje for dia `01/10/2017`

O usuario informa 20 dias, ele deve me retornar os ciclos 1, 2, 3 pois estes 3 registros estão em ate 20 dias para "vencer"

Esse `endDAte` e uma data de vencimento.

Comment: Você já conseguiu a ajuda?

Comment: a responsta do Randrade parece me servir, vou finalizar os testes aqui, obrigado pela preocupação @Francisco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos dividir isso em três passos.

Primeiro, você deve obter a data atual. Após isso, você soma essa data com a quantidade de dias informadas pelo usuário e por fim, basta adicionar em seu filtro.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
var listaCiclos = new List<Ciclos>(){
    new Ciclos() { id = 1, name = "primeiro", endDate = Convert.ToDateTime("05/10/2017") },
    new Ciclos() { id = 2, name = "segundo", endDate = Convert.ToDateTime("15/10/2017") },
    new Ciclos() { id = 3, name = "terceiro", endDate = Convert.ToDateTime("20/10/2017") },
    new Ciclos() { id = 4, name = "quarto", endDate = Convert.ToDateTime("30/10/2017") }
};


//Aqui eu adicionei a data de seu exemplo, mas você usaria Datetime.Now, para obter a data atual.
var dataAtual = Convert.ToDateTime("01/10/2017");

//Somamos a data atual mais a quantidade de dias digitado pelo usuário com o .AddDays()
var dataUsuario = dataAtual.AddDays(20);

//Filtramos a lista de acordo com os critérios informados
var listaFiltro = listaCiclos.Where(c => c.endDate > dataAtual && c.endDate < dataUsuario).ToList();
```

[Veja um exemplo funcional no .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cUfaAb)